# Deeper knowledge of os x?

Tags: macos, unix

I want to gain deeper knowledge of os x, which books/courses/forums should i take? All books that i have seen was about how to save your document in Pages. 
First of all, i will learn bash but what's next?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: bash is about Unix, not specifically OS X. It is anyway a great path to better understand your computer.

Comment: This is an admirable goal, but unless your question gets more specific about your desired outcome than "gaining deeper knowledge of os x" the answers will be, of necessity, all over the place. Please specify more about what you hope to accomplish. I'm closing this for now, but if you refine the question to something likely to have a right answer, we can reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

The book [Mac OS X and iOS Internals: To the Apple's Core](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118057651) is very good, and it comes with examples and exercises.

The [WWDC Core OS videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) are a good resource.